# Init all Bean properties

Tags: java, code-generation, javabeans

I'm working at the moment on some POJOs which are containing a huge bunch of properties. I have to ensure that all properties are initialized. Are there some util classes which could handle this for me at runtime?

A superb feature would be to check for null value and init to default value.

Comment: Initialize them with default or specific values?

Comment: default would be enough. check my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) to do this. Assuming that your POJOs follow the Java Bean naming conventions for properties and getter/setter methods, if have your property values in a `Map` you can use [`BeanUtils.populate`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#populate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map%29) to populate beans with a predefined set of property values. If you want to copy values from one bean to another, use [`BeanUtils.copyProperties`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29).